# How to quiet "Starting new Ispell process" on opening every file?

Tags: flyspell, ispell

Using  flyspell by default is handy, but the message on every file gets annoying (especially since it doesnt go away).

eg:

```
Starting new Ispell process /usr/bin/aspell with american dictionary...
```

Is there a way to disable this, or at least clear the message? I checked `ispell.el` and there wasn't an obvious way.

Comment: I commented out that section a few years ago and have never looked back until today (after reading this thread).  There is no user customization to turn that message off, which is why I commented it out.

Comment: I don't mind commenting it out, but it's annoying to need to do this each time the emacs package is updated.

Comment: A year or so ago, there was NEWS about a *new* (now *old*) way to quiet messages so that they do not show up in the echo area.  If the function at issue does not have any other important messages, you could let-bind that message suppression echo area variable with an advice to the function that gives the annoying message; e.g., `ispell-init-process`.  However, that advice would affect all messages generated by that function.  Another idea would be to copy the entire function over to your user-configuration, modify it, and load it after `ispell.el`; and, check new releases of Emacs for changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can temporarily disable `message` with the following advice for `ispell-init-process`.
That is a general approach which also works for other functions emitting unwanted messages.

```el
(defun message-off-advice (oldfun &rest args)
  "Quiet down messages in adviced OLDFUN."
  (let ((message-off (make-symbol "message-off")))
    (unwind-protect
    (progn
      (advice-add #'message :around #'ignore (list 'name message-off))
      (apply oldfun args))
    (advice-remove #'message message-off))))

(advice-add #'ispell-init-process :around #'message-off-advice)
```

Comment: This is supresing other messages (such as confirmation on exit). note that I'm using `(setq use-dialog-box nil)`.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer silenced too many (other, non-ispell) messages for me, but the approach from https://superuser.com/a/1025827 works:

```
(defun suppress-messages (old-fun &rest args)
  (cl-flet ((silence (&rest args1) (ignore)))
    (advice-add 'message :around #'silence)
    (unwind-protect
         (apply old-fun args)
      (advice-remove 'message #'silence))))

(advice-add 'ispell-init-process :around #'suppress-messages)
(advice-add 'ispell-kill-ispell :around #'suppress-messages)
```

(I would have just made a comment, but have too little reputation.)