# How to troubleshoot a key binding prompting for more key presses?

Tags: key-bindings, debugging, keymap

I have a function bound to `Ctrl-b`, this runs a command immediately, however after some time running emacs, pressing this binding shows text `C-b` in the message bar, prompting for other keys to be pressed.

If I press Enter, it runs the command, otherwise it keeps accepting key and mouse input.

`C-h k` still shows up this key binding as being associated with the function I expect it to run.

---

How to troubleshoot emacs expecting further input for a key binding?

---

Edit: the command (which I wasn't sure if it was important) is to build.

```
(defun generic-build ()
  (interactive)
  (cond
    ((string= major-mode "c-mode")
      (call-interactively 'cmake-ide-compile))
    ((string= major-mode "c++-mode")
      (call-interactively 'cmake-ide-compile))
    )
  )

(global-set-key (kbd "C-b") 'generic-build)
(eval-after-load "evil-maps"
  (define-key evil-motion-state-map "\C-b" nil))
```

---

Update 1:

This happens if I try to exit too, Pressing `Ctrk-b, Ctrl-h` shows this message.

This would have to be related to my configuration, the issue just never came up until recently.

```
Type SPC or ‘y’ to save the current buffer;
DEL or ‘n’ to skip the current buffer;
RET or ‘q’ to give up on the save (skip all remaining buffers);
C-g to quit (cancel the whole command);
! to save all remaining buffers;
C-r to view this buffer;
d to view changes in this buffer;
or . (period) to save the current buffer and exit.
```

I'm using:

```
(setq use-dialog-box nil)
```

Which has been working up until now.

Using `emacs -Q`, then setting `(setq use-dialog-box nil)` still prompts for file save.

---

Update 2:

Found the root cause, posting in answer since its confusing to include here.

Comment: If it had been converted to a prefix binding then you could type `C-b C-h` to see which bindings were using that prefix; however that does not match your description. Please update the question with details of the specific function in question. My best guess is that this is actually expected behaviour.

Comment: It's a function I wrote, it simply triggers a build. It doesnt do anything interactive. The reason this is not expected behavior is it does not do this when I first open emacs. after 10min use+ ... it starts to do it (not scientific I know, I'm just not sure what triggers it).

Comment: Do you see the same problem when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file), and then define your command and bind it to the key? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: As phils wrote, either `C-b C-h` or `C-b ?` will tell you what bindings are available. Some of those bindings must have overwritten your original one.

Comment: Show us the function.

Comment: `C-b C-h` did it! It shows text: `Type SPC or 'y' to save the current buffer`..  also other bindings. So in this particular case it seems `cmake-ide-compile` is prompting for input on an unsaved buffer. For some reason this text doesn't show by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad to know you resolved the problem. Since your question is about troubleshooting keybindings I'd like to chip in with my key troubleshooting process.

Try using `C-h b` when you can't properly query `C-h k` for the command bound to a key.
The `C-h b` (`M-x describe-bindings`) command describes all active key bindings for the buffer.

It's easy to scan this table for any clashes with an existing **prefix command**. 
A clash of this type could explain why your key was waiting for more key stroke input.

When a problem happens only after I've been interacting with Emacs for some time this is often because I indirectly loaded features when searching for their documentation with `C-h f` and `C-h v`.

In this case comparing the output of `C-h m` could help find problems introduced when a new mode is loaded, maybe unexpectedly or inadvertently.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is messages are being suppressed by this advice-function.

somehow it's not limited to `ispell-init-process`:

```el
(defun message-off-advice (oldfun &rest args)
  "Quiet down messages in adviced OLDFUN."
  (let ((message-off (make-symbol "message-off")))
    (unwind-protect
    (progn
      (advice-add #'message :around #'ignore (list 'name message-off))
      (apply oldfun args))
      (advice-remove #'message message-off))))

(advice-add #'ispell-init-process :around #'message-off-advice)
```

See answer: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/36626/2418

Comment: "somehow it's not limited to `ispell-init-process`" - yes, it completely disables `message` when `ispell-init-process` is called until that call ends. That includes asynchronous calls, since I see that `ispell-init-process` uses `accept-process-output`.